# centering a video and have overflow to hide from the top and the bottom of the container

Tags: css, html

I have the following css code:

```
<style>
    #videcontainer 
    {
    height: 400px;
    width: 1000px;

    overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

and the following HTML:

```
<div class="videocontainer">
    <video style="width: 100%;height: auto;" controls autoplay>
      <source src="video/test.mpt" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="video/test.ogg" type="video/ogg">
      <source src="video/test.webm" type="video/webm">
      <span class="nosupport">Your browser does not have support for playing this video</span>
    </video>
</div>
```

Here is what I need to do, I want to have the overflow to hide the video from both top and the bottom of the container. Basically I want the video to stay at the center of the container when the browser window gets resized. With the existing code everything works fine except when i resize the window, the hidden part of the video is always taken from the bottom.

Any idea ?

I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: do you know the aspect ratio of the video in advance?

Comment: no i don't ! i want the width to fit the container and the height to be proportional.